# Multiples botones, que lancen un solo modal sin bootstrap? Solo funciona el primero

Tags: modal

Necesito que me abra el mismo modal para todos los botones, el problema es que todas las soluciones que eh encontrado vienen con bootstrap y por el css que estoy manejando no puedo agregar el bootstrap...

```css
.bx--btn{
    font-family:"ibm-plex-sans",Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    letter-spacing:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:-ms-inline-flexbox;
    display:inline-flex;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center;
    -ms-flex-negative:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    font-size:.875rem;
    font-weight:600;
    height:2.5rem;
    padding:0 1rem;
    border-radius:0;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition-duration:250ms;
    transition-timing-function:ease-in;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:16px
}

.bx--btn--primary{
    background-color:#3d70b2;
    border-width:2px;
 font-size: 16px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent;
    color:#fff
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
 z-index: 2;
}
.modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    width: 24rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
 animation-name: modal;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 
}

.close-button {
    float: right;
    width: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.close-button:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
}
.show-modal {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;

}

@keyframes modal{
 from{top:-330px; opacity:0;}
 to{top:0; opacity:1;}

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button class="trigger bx--btn bx--btn--primary">Ver</button>
     
    <div class="modal"> 
     <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close-button">×</span>
      <h1>Hello, I am a modal!</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
        
        <button class="trigger bx--btn bx--btn--primary">Ver</button>
     
    <div class="modal"> 
     <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close-button">×</span>
      <h1>Hello, I am a modal!</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
<script>
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");

}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignar el evento directamente en el botón. El código debería quedar algo así:

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");

}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

//trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

```css
.bx--btn{
    font-family:"ibm-plex-sans",Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
    letter-spacing:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:-ms-inline-flexbox;
    display:inline-flex;
    -ms-flex-align:center;
    align-items:center;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    justify-content:center;
    -ms-flex-negative:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    font-size:.875rem;
    font-weight:600;
    height:2.5rem;
    padding:0 1rem;
    border-radius:0;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition-duration:250ms;
    transition-timing-function:ease-in;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:16px
}

.bx--btn--primary{
    background-color:#3d70b2;
    border-width:2px;
 font-size: 16px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent;
    color:#fff
}

.modal {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
 z-index: 2;
}
.modal-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    width: 24rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
 animation-name: modal;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 
}

.close-button {
    float: right;
    width: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.close-button:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
}
.show-modal {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;

}

@keyframes modal{
 from{top:-330px; opacity:0;}
 to{top:0; opacity:1;}

}
```

```html
<button class="trigger bx--btn bx--btn--primary" onclick="toggleModal();">Ver 1</button>
     
    <div class="modal"> 
     <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close-button">×</span>
      <h1>Hello, I am a modal!</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
        
        <button class="trigger bx--btn bx--btn--primary" onclick="toggleModal();">Ver 2</button>
```